# How to draw a pie chart using RectF which will be easy to support multiple screen size in android?

Tags: android, colors, pie-chart

Hi I am using following code to draw a pie chart in android :-

```
public class Chart extends View
{
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private float[] value_degree;
    private String[] Title_value;
    RectF rectf = new RectF(50, 5, 200, 150);
    Rect rect = new Rect(50, 5, 200, 150);
    float temp = 0;

    public Chart(Context context, float[] values, String[] heading)
    {
        super(context);
        value_degree = new float[values.length];
        Title_value = new String[heading.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            value_degree[i] = values[i];
            Log.i("abc", "" + values[i]);
            Title_value[i] = heading[i];
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Random r;


        int centerX = (rect.left + rect.right) / 2;
        int centerY = (rect.top + rect.bottom) / 2;
        int radius = (rect.right - rect.left) / 2;
        int color;
        radius *= 0.5; // 1 will put the text in the border, 0 will put the text
                        // in the center. Play with this to set the distance of
                        // your text.
        for (int i = 0; i < value_degree.length; i++)
        {

            if (i == 0)
            {
                r = new Random();
                color = Color.argb(100, r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256),
                        r.nextInt(256));
                paint.setColor(color);

                Log.i("Color", "" + color);

                canvas.drawArc(rectf, temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);

                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // set this to the text color.
                paint.setTextSize(12);
                /*
                 * paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
                 */float medianAngle = (temp + (value_degree[i] / 2f))
                        * (float) Math.PI / 180f; // this angle will place the
                                                    // text in the center of the
                                                    // arc.
                canvas.drawText(Title_value[i],
                        (float) (centerX + (radius * Math.cos(medianAngle))),
                        (float) (centerY + (radius * Math.sin(medianAngle))),
                        paint);

            } else
            {
                temp += value_degree[i - 1];

                r = new Random();
                color = Color.argb(255, r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256),
                        r.nextInt(256));
                paint.setColor(color);
                Log.i("Else Color", "" + color);
                canvas.drawArc(rectf, temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);

                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // set this to the text color.
                paint.setTextSize(12);
                /*
                 * paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
                 */float medianAngle = (temp + (value_degree[i] / 2f))
                        * (float) Math.PI / 180f; // this angle will place the
                                                    // text in the center of the
                                                    // arc.
                canvas.drawText(Title_value[i],
                        (float) (centerX + (radius * Math.cos(medianAngle))),
                        (float) (centerY + (radius * Math.sin(medianAngle))),
                        paint);

            }


        }



    }
}
```

It is showing chart in good quality in small screen sizes. But when I check it on big screen like S4 or other same screen size device it is shows a pie chart in very small size.
What should I do so it will draw perfectly on small as well as big screens?
Please help me, suggest something.
Also suggest how can I take color value to each slice in pie chart as it is assigned randomly.